# How to force machines connected to an AP to use the local AP DNS?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, dynamic-dns, dig, nslookup

I am sharing documents by running a hotspot in conjonction to `dnsmasq` that redirect all name queries to an IP `<IP>` where the documents can be found

```
 create_ap wlan0 wlan0 HereAreTheDocuments
 echo "address=/#/<IP>" >> /dev/dnsmasq.conf
 service dnsmasq start
```

I need to force users connected to my hotspot to set my IP as their DNS.

**How can I force connected users to use the local DNS instead of a remote one?**

For instance lots of machine are using Google DNS at `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Comment: O hope you're not actually using 127.0.0.1 as your address there, as that won't work (that always means the local machine, so to the client machine, it'll mean the client machine). Also, why aren't your client machines getting the correct DNS server from DHCP?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331777/ for a connected question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally end up using `dnsspoof` in conjunction to `dnsmasq`.

Please tell if you have an alternative to `dnsspoof`.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT
```